# How do I check if an issue with a tag exists on my GitHub repo using the API?

Tags: bash, github-api

So I have this code below that automatically runs once every hour but the problem is that whenever there is a merge conflict, it creates an issue regardless if it exists or not, so I end up with a bunch of duplicate issues in the repo. How do I check if an issue with the "Merge Conflict" tag exists so it doesn't create duplicate issues?

This is only a portion of the code that matters:

```
CONFLICTS=$(git ls-files -u | wc -l)
if [ "$CONFLICTS" -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "There is a merge conflict. Aborting"
    git merge --abort
    curl -u $GITHUB_USER:$GITHUB_SECRET_TOKEN -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title": "Merge conflict detected", "body": "Heroku could not update your repo. Please check for merge conflicts and update manually!","labels": ["merge conflict"]}' https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPO/issues
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Search issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues-and-pull-requests) using the following search parameters :

- repo:username/repo
- state:open
- label:"merge conflict" (check [this](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/))

In the UI : https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AMacley-Kun%2Favaire+state%3Aopen+label%3A%22merge+conflict%22

#### Using Github API Rest v3

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo%3AMacley-Kun%2Favaire%20state%3Aopen%20label%3A%22merge%20conflict%22

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to check if this repo at least one issue labelled "merge conflict" (case insensitive)

```bash
query='repo:Macley-Kun/avaire state:open label:"merge conflict"'

merge_conflicts=$(curl -G -s "https://api.github.com/search/issues" \
     --data-urlencode "q=$query" | jq '.items | length')

if [ "$merge_conflicts" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "no opened merge conflicts issue detected"
else
    echo "one or many merge conflicts issues already exist"
fi
```

#### Using Github API Graphql v4

```graphql
{
  search(query: "repo:Macley-Kun/avaire state:open label:\"merge conflict\"", type: ISSUE, first: 0) {
    issueCount
  }
}
```

[Try it from the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22repo%3AMacley-Kun%2Favaire%20state%3Aopen%20label%3A%5C%22merge%20conflict%5C%22%22%2C%20type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20first%3A%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issueCount%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
repo=Macley-Kun/avaire

merge_conflicts=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{search(query: \"repo:'"$REPO"' state:open label:\\\"merge conflict\\\"\", type: ISSUE, first: 0) {issueCount}}"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql | jq '.data.search.issueCount')

if [ "$merge_conflicts" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "no opened merge conflicts issue detected"
else
    echo "one or many merge conflicts issues already exist"
fi
```